# SQlAlchemy __tablename__ NameError

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm completely new to SQlAlchemy and, trying to get it, I wrote the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Collection(Base):
    __tablename__ == 'Collection'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Sheet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sheet'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    collection_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('collection.id'))

def main():
    base_name = 'test.db'
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format(base_name))
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And when I run this script I get:

> NameError: name '**tablename**' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `__tablename__ == 'Collection'` You have two `=`.

Comment: @univerio I cannot believe that I'm so stupid. Do I deserve capital punishment for my stupidity?)
Write your comment as the answer. I'll approve it with tears in eyes =(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a comparison operator `==` instead of an assignment operator `=` in your definition of `Collection`:

```
__tablename__ == 'Collection'
```

Comment: `__tablename__ = 'Collection'` as the correction instead of `__tablename__ == 'Collection'`